# Guest wifi login page forward

Tags: networking, login

At work and at hotels for Guest wifi I need to login via a web page.
I connect to the wifi SSID no problem, but have no internet until I login.
Only issue is that whenever I open a webpage via FF or Chrome it never forwards to the login screen for the wifi.
I've tried fresh installs of 16.04, KDE Neon and so on, all have the same issue.
I can get it to work if I try on a different device and type in the login page name it then works. But its not overly effective especially when at a hotel.

Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: Captive portals can only redirect you if you try to access a website which uses plain http - it can't redirect you to the login page if you type / go to a https address. So connect, open your browser, and go to a website which doesn't use HTTPS - I use [example.com](http://example.com), and then you should get redirected to the login page.

Comment: @JonasCz thanks but I tried that. Went to google.co.uk and other sites to test, but nothing forwarded to the login pages

Comment: Does it show you any specific error message ? Try right clicking on the nework icon in the top panel > edit connections > find your network in the list and click edit > under ipv4 settings make sure it's set to "auto (DHCP)" Google forces HTTPS, so you need to use something else. What do you see when you type `curl -v example.com`  in a terminal ?

Comment: Thanks Jonas, will give that a try when I find another guest wifi login.